# How to raise cell click event on clicking the particular cell of DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Anyone Please help with C# coding for how to raise the event when the particular cell (for example, column name is "EmployeeName") of DataGridView is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the CellContentClick event, then check if the column is your column:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == clmEmployeeName.Index)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this ..

The DataGridViewCellEventArgs can be used to determine what the position of that cell in the grid is:

```
 DataGridViewCell cell = (DataGridViewCell) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex]; 

 if (cell.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumn"].Index) 
 { 
    // Do something when a "YourColumn" cell is clicked 
 } 
 else if (cell.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["AnotherColumn"].Index) 
 { 
     // Do something when an "AnotherColumn" cell is clicked 
 }
```